# how to validate three inputs as if they were only one in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm working in react and ant design. I need to validate 3 numbers input(hour, minutes and seconds) as if they were only. If they are empty,then show error message as like "into duration completly". excuse for my english

**My code**

```
    <Form.Item name='duration' label="duration" {...formItemLayouDurationCost}
            labelAlign="right"
            wrapperCol={{ xs: 24 }}
        >
           <InputNumber max={60} min={0} placeholder="hh" />
           <InputNumber max={60} min={1} placeholder="mm" />
           <InputNumber max={60} min={1} placeholder="ss" />
        </Form.Item>
```

thank you so much

Comment: You should use [`DatePicker`](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) with `picker="time"` prop.

Comment: No my friend. dateTime, has a limit in hour that is 24, I need ilimited hour, such as 100 hours.Excuse for my English

Comment: Gotcha, take a look at [customized form controls](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below. onChange only gets the value that was changed
A curried function will help here.

```
changeHandler = name => value => {
     console.log(name, value);
  };
```

-----Sample--------

```
import {Form,InputNumber} from 'antd'
import React,{useState} from 'react';
export const TestComponent =()=>{
  const [hour,setHours]=useState(0);
  const [minutes,setMinutes]=useState(0);
  const [seconds,setSeconds]=useState(0);
  
  const changeHandler = name => value => {
    console.log(name, value);
    switch(name){
      case "hour":
          setHours(parseInt(value));
          // do other logic 
       break;
       case "minutes":
          setMinutes(parseInt(value));
            // do other logic 
         break;
      case "seconds":
          setSeconds(parseInt(value));
            // do other logic 
       default:
         break;
    }
 };



  return(
    <Form.Item name='duration' label="duration" 
    labelAlign="right"
    wrapperCol={{ xs: 24 }}
>
   <InputNumber max={60} min={0} placeholder="hh" onChange={changeHandler("hours")} />
   <InputNumber max={60} min={1} placeholder="mm"  onChange={changeHandler("minutes")}/>
   <InputNumber max={60} min={1} placeholder="ss" onChange={changeHandler("seconds")}/>
</Form.Item>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, and then tell you friend. Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok np. Let me know if you need any additional information.